# Excel VBA To Extract Data From a TD

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to extract the search result names from a table on a webpage (https://lambda.byu.edu/ae/prod/person/cgi/personLookup.cgi).

In the past, I've used code like the following to extract data from a webpage. But I can't seem to figure out how to extract the text from a td tag. The code I’m using gives me a Run-time error ‘424’: Object required.

Any suggestions?

```
    Sub Macro1()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
IE.navigate "https://lambda.byu.edu/ae/prod/person/cgi/personLookup.cgi"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim i As Integer, iNumberOfLoops As Integer
iNumberOfLoops = Sheets("Extract").Range("D2").Value

For i = 1 To iNumberOfLoops

IE.document.all("inpSearchPattern").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract").Range("A1")

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
       'MsgBox "i= " & i & " Name " & objCollection(I).Name & _
        " Value " & objCollection(I).Value & _
        " Type " & objCollection(I).Type
       If (objCollection(i).Value = "Lookup" And objCollection(i).Type = "button") Then
           Set objElement = objCollection(i)
       End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click
              
Dim aA As String
aA = Trim(Doc.getElementByTagName("td")(0).innerText)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").Value = aA

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do a search on the form. In order to get results to populate, you either need to fill out some search criteria and complete the search, or, it appears you can do a `POST` to get the values back from the server

Comment: You're getting an error 424 because `Doc` isn't set to anything. Where do you set this?

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to shorten the code, for simplicity sake. Looks like that was a mistake. Lesson learned. I'll edit the original code. And, hopefully, that will be helpful.

Comment: `aA = Trim(IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText)` but you need to wait for the page to load after clicking the "Lookup" button.

Comment: Oh, my goodness, Tim! I'm so sorry. I totally spaced it and didn't even see your comment.  This is great! Thank you! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a POST XHR request and pass in searchPattern (last name) and firstName params in the body. Wildcards are supported. Additionally, a Content-Type header is needed with VBA.

You should test that the results table is actually present before attempting to write out. As this is an example to help you I haven't gone to writing out the whole table using a loop (also the table is a mess!). I simply use the clipboard to copy paste with source formatting so table written out is as per website. You can decide how you want to deal with the retrieved table.

If ultimately you are doing multiple lookups then use a loop but create re-usable objects before the loop e.g. `xhr` and `clipboard`, and construct the `body` within the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindStaff()
    'tools > references > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, xhr As Object
    
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim body As String
    
    With xhr
         'here is where you would implement a loop
        .Open "POST", "https://lambda.byu.edu/ae/prod/person/cgi/personLookup.cgi", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         body = "searchPattern=*&firstName=Scott"    'you could construct this from values in cells. searchPattern is Last Name and/or wildcards
        .send body
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With   'if looping this would move down to after the End If
    
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
    
    Set table = html.querySelector("#Content table")
    
    If table Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No results!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim clipboard As Object
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText table.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial '<- Alter this to destination. Example alter row for where to write out in a loop.
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works! I don't know that I understand all that is going on here. And, so, I'll have to try and study out what you've done here. But it works! Thank you so, so much! I wasn't going to figure this out on my own.

Comment: See https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ regarding xhr (xmlhttp) POST and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator regarding `html.querySelector("#Content table")`

Comment: Question: In your comments, you talked about the possibility of looping. Typically, if I was going to try an loop through the results of this kind of query, I would use some sort of code like the following:

For Each aTag In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If aTag.innerText = "Next Page >>" Then
        aTag.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next aTag

But I'm pretty sure I'm way in over my head here, as far as trying to navigate to any subsequent results pages. How does one navigate to the subsequent results page?

Comment: Do it manually in the webpage and examine what happens in the network tab when you select a new page. It is likely there is a POST request XHR with a pagination or offset parameter. That will form the basis of your updated code. You also need to think about what will terminate the loop. Typically this is by determining the result page count in advance or looping until some element is not present.

Comment: I don't know much about POST XHR requests. Is there a way to do a POST XHR request that would open an IE browser?

Comment: The advantage of POST XHR is that there is no browser involved. See https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/  and https://scrapecrow.com/reverse-engineering-intro.html

Comment: Thanks, again, @QHarr; very helpful, as always. My challenge is several fold: 1.) It looks like *extracting* the search result names is less important than I thought it was going to be. Turns out that *seeing* the result is going to be more helpful for me (which is partly why I'm hoping to have the code open up a web browser). My mistake; not yours.

Comment: And 2.) I'm totally new to POST XHR requests. I love that POST XHR requests supports wildcards. Is there a way to eihter do a POST XHR request that would open an IE browser or use something closer to the orininal code I posted and search with wildcards? I've tried using this bit of code, but no luck: IE.document.all("inpSearchPattern").Value = "A**"